# Create pandas dataframe with unequal list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Is there a built-in function apart from `DataFrame.from_dict` able to create a dataframe from a dictionary with unequal list of values?

What I am trying to do create a dataframe from the following dictionary:

```
d = {'g': {1, 2, 3}, 'h': {4, 5}}
```

so the output should look like:

```
   value  class
0    1        g
1    2        g
2    3        g
3    4        h
4    5        h
```

Is having the set instead of a list a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind manually unwrapping, you can achieve this through

```
In [9]: pd.DataFrame([(x, k) for k, v in d.items() for x in v], columns=['value', 'class'])
Out[9]:
   value class
0      1     g
1      2     g
2      3     g
3      4     h
4      5     h
```

Answer (score 7):

Yet another way using `melt`

```
pd.DataFrame(d.values(), d.keys()).T.melt().dropna()
```

Comment: interesting... didn't know about melt. Thansk :)

Comment: @KennethRivadeneiraGuadamud you can consider upvoting the answers that helped you. :)

Comment: I'd need more details than that ;]

Comment: I think it needs list. pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()), list(d.keys())).T.melt().dropna()   I like this solution better. :)

Comment: @run-out I think depending on the pandas version you're using, you need to add `list()` you're right ;}

Comment: Ah. I see. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939)

```
unnesting(pd.Series(d).apply(list).to_frame('name'),['name']).reset_index()
  index  name
0     g     1
1     g     2
2     g     3
3     h     4
4     h     5
```